# ggplot geom_line colour line on direction

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add scale colour to geom_line() to indicate line segment is upwards/downwards - without having to pre-process data with reshape, dcast and create an another variable  ?

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

my.data <- data.table(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), 
                  loc = c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"),
                  value = c(10.3,11.5,12.5,12.1,10.5,9.8,9.7,10.7))

p<-ggplot(my.data ,aes(x=loc,y=value,group=id)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: I can't imagine a way for `geom_line()` to know whether or not the segment goes upwards. I'm afraid you'll have to provide the information somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do

```
ggplot(my.data, aes(x=loc,y=value,group=id)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=ave(value,id,FUN=diff)>=0))
```